# Preventing a BindingExpression Error on a property that does not always exist

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm desperately trying to prevent a BindingExpression error from happening when Binding on a property which is not always existing at runtime.

I'm using the MVVM pattern, and I've got a ViewModel in which I keep track of the `SelectedItem` of a `TreeView`. The main problematic is that the `SelectedItem` can be of different types, each type having its own properties and specificities.

Then, I want to make a Binding like such (for example) :

```xml
<ToggleButton IsChecked={Binding SelectedItem.IsTextBold}/>
```

The problem is this always throws a BindingExpression Error `Property IsTextBold not found on object FooBarViewModel` when the wrong `TreeViewItem` is selected (which happens a lot, since I've got plenty of different objects in my TreeView).

Here is an example of code of a basic WPF app which reproduces the same behaviour, but with a ListView (so it is easier to reproduce, but the result is exactly the same) :
`MainWindow.xaml` :

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.IsChecked}"/> <!-- This is the button I want to do a Binding on with the SelectedItem of the ListBox -->

        <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" TextAlignment="Center" Width="500"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" Width="500"/>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs` :

```cs
namespace WpfApp1
{
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

`MainWindowViewModel.cs` :

```cs
namespace WpfApp1
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private object _selectedItem;
        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return this._selectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                this._selectedItem = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried the two following solutions, and none of them worked :

- Using `Style.Triggers` on the `ToggleButton` I want to bind, using a Converter to check the type of `SelectedItem`. This works until the `SelectedItem` is of the right type, but then it throws the BindingExpression error again, since the Binding was "activated" by clicking on the good element in the first place, and not "deactivated" when clicking back on the wrong element.
- Trying to do a MarkupExtension used to wrap the `Binding`. I added an EventHandler on the `Binding.TargetUpdatedEvent` to try and check the property used for the Binding using Reflection, but this event occurs after the BindingExpression error is thrown, so it was worthless.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the binding path is invalid? It `SelectedItem` may be bound to objects of different types, they should have a common base type where you define the property that you bind to for no binding errors to occur.

Comment: @mm8 To put a little more context, I'm working on a "Word-like" software, so the `SelectedItem` may be a RichTextBoxViewModel, a DataGridViewModel or even a custom UserControlViewModel that I've made for specific pruposes. I understand your point of view, but in this context it would make no sense for me to have a common base type with every single property I would want to do a Binding on :/

I'd like to find a way to avoid having BindingExpression errors when the Binding is invalid for these reasons.

Comment: A source property should never return a control like a `RichTextBox` or `DataGrid`. This is not MVVM.

Comment: @mm8 I'm sorry, I meant to speak of the ViewModels of my controls, of course :)

Comment: So move `IsChecked` to a common base class for the view models?

Comment: @mm8 The thing is, in my project, `SelectedItem` already is a base type from which all the possible `ViewModels` in my TreeView inherit. But it would make no sense for me to have such properties in this base type, because it would mix up all my UserControls behaviours : I would end up having a BaseViewModel with, for example, properties such as `IsTextBold` (from a RichTextBox VM), `MinValue` (from a custom DataGrid VM), `IsElemChecked` (from a custom ToggleButton VM), etc...

Comment: Then it doesn't make any sense to use the same binding either.

Comment: Generally, the right way to deal with "property doesn't exist" is to not provide a template that demands that property in the first place. The WPF layout engine allows you to specify templates for specific types for a reason, foremost being that you know when you declare the binding that a property _does_ exist. If you don't like that, then the exact mechanism you need depends a lot on goals and requirements not stated in your question. If the duplicate does not address your needs, post a new question with sufficient details to know what you've tried and what _specifically_ you need help with.